# Mockito when() not firing

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following structure:

```
List<MyObject> moList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
processor.set(moList);    //This is initialized earlier

KeyValueStore<MyObject> moStore = mock(KeyValueStore.class);
when(moStore.add(eq(expectedKey), eq(mo))).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

processor.setMoStore(moStore);
MyObject mo = new MyObject();
mo.setEmail("abc@123");
mo.setId("123");
moList.add(mo);

processor.process();

expectedKey = MyUtils.getHex("123_abc@123");       

ArgumentCaptor<String> strArg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
ArgumentCaptor<MyObject> moArg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyObject.class);

verify(moStore).add(strArg.capture(), moArg.capture());

assertEquals(expectedKey, strArg.getValue());
assertEquals(mo, moArg.getValue());
```

Within the process, I call `moStore.add()` on the members of the moList with the derived expected key and the mo object. This is captured by the verify, and the `assertEquals` works.  However, the `when()` does not fire and the exception (there for demonstration purposes, to make sure that I don't miss it) does not occur.

I am not sure what is going on here.  The verify and the asserts pass, indicating that the `add()` was executed, but the when never fires.  When I run the test it completes successfully, even though it should throw the exception.

EDIT:
I have changed my code to proposed structure where it is now as follows:

```
List<MyObject> moList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
processor.set(moList);    //This is initialized earlier

KeyValueStore<MyObject> moStore = mock(KeyValueStore.class);

processor.setMoStore(moStore);
MyObject mo = new MyObject();
mo.setEmail("abc@123");
mo.setId("123");
moList.add(mo);

when(moStore.add(eq(expectedKey), eq(mo))).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

processor.process();

expectedKey = MyUtils.getHex("123_abc@123");       

ArgumentCaptor<String> strArg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
ArgumentCaptor<MyObject> moArg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyObject.class);

verify(moStore).add(strArg.capture(), moArg.capture());

assertEquals(expectedKey, strArg.getValue());
assertEquals(mo, moArg.getValue());
```

The problem remains:  The `assertEquals` evaluate to true, but the `when` does not fire the `RuntimeException`.  Even if I put the `when` after the `process`, or if I substitute `when(moStore.add(anyString(), any(MyObject.class))).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());` the `when` does not fire.
How is the verify doing the verification correctly but the when is not firing?  The two should give the same result, from what I know.

Comment: Niek Haarman's answer is correct, but it's worth pointing out a couple of things you're doing in a less-than-efficient way.  (1) You don't need to apply `eq` to every argument inside your `when` - you can just write `when(moStore.add(expectedKey, mo))` etc.  In either case, Mockito will do the same thing, which is to use `equals` to compare the arguments passed to `add` with the arguments in your stubbing call.  (2) There's no need to use `ArgumentCaptor`s in your `verify`, if all you're going to do is check the captured values using `assertEquals`.  The last five lines of your test could ...

Comment: ... be replaced by just one, that is `verify(moStore).add(expectedKey, mo);`.  And of course, in a real test there's rarely any point in both stubbing and verifying the same method call - if the behaviour that you stubbed occurred, there's no need for a `verify`; and if your test can't tell whether the behaviour that you stubbed occurred, then the stub must have been redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
when(moStore.add(eq(expectedKey), eq(mo))).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

processor.setMoStore(moStore);
MyObject mo = new MyObject();
mo.setEmail("abc@123");
mo.setId("123");
moList.add(mo);
```

You say `eq(mo)`, and *then* initialize `mo` to a new `MyObject`. The `eq` matcher has a wrong reference, and it will not match on your new `MyObject`.

Try initializing the `mo` object first, and *then* executing `when`.

Comment: Exactly; and not only that, but if `MyObject` does not implement equals() and hashCode() correctly, `same()` should be used instead of `eq()`.